# How to allgatherv from multiple arrays

Tags: mpi

Here is the situation: each task mush share data from a variable number of subarrays from 3 different arrays (a1, a2, a3), all of the same type, with each subarray being of different length.
My current solution is to pack things manually to end up with a single array to share via a single allgatherv.
Can the same be achieved using e.g. a derived datatype to avoid manually packing?

Comment: you can definitely use a derived datatype on the non root ranks. On the root rank, it depends how regular your data layout is. Please post some code if you expect a more definitive answer.

Comment: The data layout would look like this:
task0: 1111112233333122222333
task1: nothing
task2  111111111111111122233

On each task I then want to end up with (hence the use of a collective):
1111112233333122222333111111111111111122233
Where the 1s are contiguous elements from a1, 2s from a2, and 3s from a3.

Comment: sorry, I only understand code :-)